# How to instantiate an object of a class from within the class itself?

Tags: python, class, oop

Below is a simplified version of my code:

In *TestClass.py* file:

```
class TestClass:

    def func1(self):
        pass

    def func2(self):
        HERE I WANT TO CALL func1
```

And in the *main.py* file:

```
TestClass1 = TestClass()
TestClass1.func2()
```

Initially, I have tried to run `func1` from `func2` in the following way (in *TestClass.py*):

```
TestClass.func2()
```

But in this case I have received the following error message:

```
TypeError: unbound method func1() must be called with TestClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

So the way I understand this problem is that there is no `TestClass1` instance within `TestClass` itself, it only exists in the main(calling) code. So in order to fix that I have passed the instance of `TestClass` while calling the `func2` from the *main.py*:

```
TestClass.func2(TestClass1)
```

And I have added it (the class) to the `func2` as a mandatory argument accordingly.
**As a result, it seem working fine.** But I wanted to make sure that's it's an accepted way to do that.

Comment: Use `self.func1()` form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a python guru but it seems that you'll need to call `func1` and `func2` using the `self` reference this is similar to `this` in java.